# Unsatisfiable solution with `constraint forall(i in x)( x[i] <= x[i+1] );`

Tags: minizinc, optimathsat

I'm working on a toy problem to learn minizinc.  Take an array (hardcoded to size 3 for now) of values between 0 and 9 and find the combinations where the sum is equal to the product.

```
par int: n = 3; % hardcode for now 

array[1..n] of var 0..9: x;

constraint sum(x) != 0;
constraint sum(x) == product(x);

output["\(x)"];
```

Outputs

```
[2, 3, 1]
----------
```

This works as expected, however, next I try to constrain so that the values must increase in order.

First I tried this:

```
constraint forall(i in x)( 
   x[i] <= x[i+1]
);
```

This was UNSATISFIABLE.  I was thinking this could be due to the `i+1` index being greater than the size of the array for the last item.  So I added a condition to the forall to prevent the index of the last item being out of bounds:

```
constraint forall(i in x)( 
   i < n /\ x[i] <= x[i+1]
);
```

However, this was also UNSATISFIABLE.

Something is amiss with my conceptual understanding.  What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PROBLEM(s).**

In general, the constraint is fine. In the context of this example, however, it is inconsistent. Let's see why this is the case.

We know that the solution must include `1, 2, 3`, thus, we can infer that the constraint

```
constraint forall (i in x) (
    x[i] <= x[i+1]
);
```

is "equivalent" to

```
constraint x[1] <= x[2];
constraint x[2] <= x[3];
constraint x[3] <= x[4];
```

for which `mzn2fzn` reports the following issue:

```
  WARNING: undefined result becomes false in Boolean context
  (array access out of bounds)
  ./t.mzn:12:
  in binary '<=' operator expression
  in array access
```

When the same constraint is written without hard-encoded index values, the `mzn2fzn` compiler is unable to detect the inconsistency before the solver is invoked. However, the semantics of the `access out of bounds` is still the same (i.e. `false`) at run-time, so the formula becomes unsatisfiable.

The constraint

```
constraint forall(i in x)( 
   i < n /\ x[i] <= x[i+1]
);
```

augments the previous constraint with the requirement that `i` must be smaller than `n`. This is clearly false for `i = 3`, so there is one more inconsistency in the model. The constraint would be correct if you used the implication symbol `->` instead of the (logical) and symbol `/\`.

---

**SOLUTION(s).**

First, let me set aside a possible misunderstanding of the language. The comprehension `i in x`, which you used in your model, refers to the elements inside the array `x`, and not to the index set of `x`. In this particular case the solution and the index set of `x` contain the same values, so it does not cause an inconsistency. However, this is not true in general, so it's better to use the function `index_set()` as follows:

```
constraint forall(i, j in index_set(x) where i < j)(
   x[i] <= x[j]
);
```

**example**:

```
par int: n = 3; % hardcode for now 

array[1..n] of var 0..9: x;

constraint sum(x) != 0;
constraint sum(x) == product(x);

constraint forall(i, j in index_set(x) where i < j)(
   x[i] <= x[j]
);

solve satisfy;

output["\(x)"];
```

yields

```
~$ mzn2fzn test.mzn 
~$ optimathsat -input=fzn < test.fzn 
x = array1d(1..3, [1, 2, 3]);
----------
```

---

A more **elegant solution** is to use the following global constraint, which is mentioned in the [documentation (v. 2.2.3)](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.2.3/en/lib-globals.html) of `MiniZinc`:

```
predicate increasing(array [int] of var bool: x)
predicate increasing(array [int] of var int: x)
predicate increasing(array [int] of var float: x)
```

The predicate admits duplicate values in the array, that is, it enforces a non-strict increasing order (if that is needed, combine `increasing` with `distinct`).

The predicate is contained in the file `increasing.mzn`. However, people normally include the file `globals.mzn` instead, so as to have access to all predicates at once.

**example**:

```
include "globals.mzn";

par int: n = 3; % hardcode for now 

array[1..n] of var 0..9: x;

constraint sum(x) != 0;
constraint sum(x) == product(x);

constraint increasing(x);

solve satisfy;

output["\(x)"];
```

yields

```
~$ mzn2fzn t.mzn 
~$ optimathsat -input=fzn < t.fzn 
x = array1d(1..3, [1, 2, 3]);
----------
```